# Reach to the destination in a matrix after visiting each cell exactly once

Tags: algorithm, matrix, graph

Traverse a given 2-D matrix from given source to destination in such way that every cell should be visited exactly one time (we have to cover all cells of matrix exactly once and have to reach at destination).
What i could get is-

1.It is not always possible.

2.It is a variation of Hamiltonian path where nodes are cells and edge is between the adjacent cells.

Is there any other solution to get the answer the path if exists else return -1.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear to me whether your question concerns a rectangular grid graph, or a general grid graph.

In either case the answer is given in
 [A. Itai, C.H. Papadimitriou, J.L. Szwarcﬁter, Hamiltonian paths in grid graphs,
SIAM J. Comput. 11 (1982) 676–686](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~itai/publications/Algorithms/Hamilton-paths.pdf).

The difference between these two is that a rectangular grid graph means that you can go anywhere in the matrix, whereas for a general grid graph some of the entries in the matrix are forbidden to be entered.

For a rectangular grid graph the paper gives a condition to say whether a route is possible or not for a given source and destination.

For a general grid graph the paper proves the problem is NP-complete.